# Holonomies for BF theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, topological-field-theory

I am trying to understand the basic properties of BF theory, but I am unable to derive the holonomies of the fields.
In my case I want to study a more general version of $BF$ theory defined on a $4d$ manifold by the following Lagrangian

\begin{equation}
L =n B \wedge dA,
\end{equation}

with $B$ a 2 form, $dA$ the curvature of a one form $A$ and $n$ an integer. As far as I understand one can show that integrating B in the path integral fixes $dA=0$ and enforces $\oint_{\gamma} A \in \frac{2 \pi}{n} \mathbb{Z} $. If I try to perform the calculation myself I easily find $dA=0$ but I am unable to reproduce the condition on the holonomies of $A$.

I found [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35658/) question which explains how to approach the calculation but at some point the author took advantage of the decomposition

\begin{equation}
dB = d\beta + \sum_k m_k \lambda_k,
\end{equation}

with $\beta$ a 2 form and $\{\lambda_k \} $ a basis of harmonic 3 forms. This decomposition does not make sense to me. $dB$ is an exact form so i do not see why its decomposition should contain also the harmonics $\lambda_k$. I would omit the term proportional to $\lambda_k$ having only $dB= d \beta$.

Could anyone explain the general procedure to obtain the holonomies of this BF theory or at least justify why the decomposition of $dB$ with both terms is valid?

As a side note one can carry out the same procedure integrating $A$ and obtaining similar conditions on $B$. $dB=0$ and $ \oint_{\sigma} B \in \frac{2 \pi}{n} \mathbb{Z} $.

**EDIT**

I have given the matter some thoughts and I think I came up with a reasonable solution so at this point I am just looking for a second opinion.

Consider the field strength $F_B= dB$. Notice that locally $F_B$ is always exact, however since $B$ is a gauge field with potentially non trivial transition functions then we are not guaranteed that $F_B$ is globally exact. For example i could divide my spacetime in two patches $U_+$ and $U_-$ and define two field $B_+$ and $B_-$ on each patch. The fields $B_+$ and $B_-$ are connected by a gauge transformation in the intersection of $U_+$ and $U_-$. On each patch $F_B$ is exact and given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F_{B+}=dB_+ &\quad \text{on} \quad U_+ \\
F_{B-}=dB_- &\quad \text{on} \quad U_-.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now assume that $U_+$ intersects $U_-$ on its boundary, that is $U_+ \cap U_-=\partial U_+$. In this situation it turns out that $F_B$ is exact on $U_+$ and $U_-$ but on $U_+ \cap U_-$ and in particular it can pick up an extra term like
\begin{equation}
F_B=dB+J(\partial U_+),
\end{equation}
where $J(\partial U_+)$ is 3-form with support on $\partial U_+$. This would explain why it is possible to decompose $F_B=dB$ can be decomposed in an exact form plus a sum of harmonic forms.

If I understand correctly this is the same mechanism that leads to the Dirac string using the Wu-Yang approach, and I am wondering if this is the correct path to take also for $BF$ theory.

*side note:* If anyone is interested in a more complete review of BF theory I suggest taking a look at appendices $A$ and $B$ of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148).

Comment: Are you interested in torsion manifolds or non-torsion only? (non-torsion means $H^*(M;\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}^{b_*(M)}$, while torsion has $H^*(M;\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}^{b_*(M)}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{k_1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{k_2}\oplus\cdots$)

Comment: I would like both cases, but it would probably be better to start with non-torsion manifolds.